# How can I create cached files within CakePHP Plugin?

Tags: cakephp, caching, cakephp-2.0

I have created a plugin for CakePHP that I would like to generate cached files within its own plugin folder at  `/app/Plugin/MyPlugin/tmp/cache`.

I have already cerated the `MyPlugin/tmp/cache` directory manually.

I have created a bootstrap file at `/app/Plugin/MyPlugin/Config/bootstrap.php` with the following content:

```
<?php
    Cache::config('short', array(
        'engine' => 'File',
        'duration' => '+60 minutes',
        'path' => 'Plugin/MyPlugin/tmp/cache',
        'prefix' => 'cake_short_',
        'mask' => 0666,
    ));
```

I have created a **Shell** script at  `/app/Plugin/MyPlugin/Console/Command/MyPluginShell.php` with the following function:

```
<?php
    ...

    public function get_listings() {
        $listings = $this->Listing->find('all');
        Cache::write('listings', $listings, 'short');
        $this->out('Task Completed');
    }
```

I can run `get_listings` from within the Cake console just fine and the Task completes, however there is no Cache file being created at `/app/Plugin/MyPlugin/tmp/cache` like I would expect.

On a side note, I have tried replacing  `'path' => 'Plugin/MyPlugin/tmp/cache'` with `'path' => CACHE` just to see if it will appear in `app/tmp/cache` but haven't had any luck.

I have also created the `/app/Plugin/MyPlugin/tmp/cache` within the plugin.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out.

I wasn't loading the plugin correctly within `app/Config/bootstrap.php`.

I was doing this (incorrect):

```
CakePlugin::load('MyPlugin', array('routes' => true));
```

Instead of this (correct):

```
CakePlugin::load('MyPlugin', array('routes' => true, 'bootstrap' => true));
```

Comment: Yes, but I have to wait 2 days after asking the original question.